# Javascript Binding Issue

Tags: javascript

This is the code snippet that makes me confusing:

```
var timer = 
{
    start: function()
    {
        var self = this;

        /*Why the code below doesn't write to this:
            window.setInterval(self.tick, 1000).*/

        //Instead, it embedded into a function like this:
        window.setInterval(function(){self.tick();}, 1000)
    },
    tick: function()
    {
        console.log("tick!");
    }       
}

timer.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that JavaScript's `this` is dynamic. When you call a function like:

```
object.func();
```

`this` will be set to `object`. However, when you call a function plainly:

```
func();
```

Or pass it to a number of other functions (`setInterval` included),  `this` will be set to the global object (`window`, usually).

Thus, when you just pass `self.tick` to `setInterval`, then `this` inside of `tick` will be the global object, not `timer`. When you pass `function() { self.tick(); }`, it is `self` (`timer`).

Here, it makes no difference, since `tick` does not access `this`, but if `tick` accessed `this`, you'd probably want to use `function() { self.tick(); }`, because otherwise, you'll be modifying properties of the global object, not `timer`.

Answer (score 1):

`function(){self.tick();}` is easier to expand later than `self.tick`. It's kind of like the difference between using curly braces (or not) around an `if` block that contains only one statement.

Comment: And why wouldn't someone later just add whatever to `tick` instead?

Comment: Because maybe `tick` could be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason we use: `window.setInterval(function(){self.tick();}, 1000)` is to conform to "Single responsibility" design principle. tick() should do only 1 job: tick. If you need to do more jobs when the timer fires, you should write another function and get it called inside the event handler instead of modifying the tick(). For example:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    self.tick();
    self.notify();
    .....
    }, 1000)
```