# javascript scope issue with "this"

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
var timer = 
{
    i: "Hello",

    start: function()
    {       
        var self = this;             
        window.setInterval(self.tick, 1000);     
    },

    tick: function()
    {
        console.log(this.i);
    }       
}

timer.start();
```

Why the javascript console displays `undefined`?

Comment: Because `this` in JavaScript works differently than in most other languages. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858507/javascript-binding-issue .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your passing a reference to `tick`, but not the scope. try:

```
start: function(){       
    var self = this;             
    window.setInterval(function(){self.tick();}, 1000);     
}
```

Or use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (look at the browser compatibility first)

Answer (score 2):

change this.i to timer.i

Or use an object declaration like

```
function timer() {
var self = this;
.. etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

suggest change `window.setInterval(self.tick, 1000);` to

```
window.setInterval(self.tick.bind(self), 1000);
```